# Is it forbidden to learn Hebrew/Aramaic during Tisha B Av?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, tisha-bav, language

Hebrew and Aramaic are languages of Jewish sefarim (religious books) and it is forbidden to learn/read sefarim during Tisha B Av because it gives joy to man to do so.

Is it then likewise forbidden to learn Hebrew/Aramaic in order, during Tisha B Av, to get a better understanding of sefarim in the original, considering that the reason for doing so is connected with learning (talmud torah), which is forbidden?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. The Gemarah is mainly Aramaic, and other than selected items, you cannot learn Gemarah. Are you referring to just studying Hebrew or Aramaic vocabulary words, such as a dictionary? I don't think that's a problem.

Comment: What about learning English?